# Text file content match if else image Resolution

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, sed

I'm working on a project where I need to cat out the images and videos Resolution if they are not equal script should exit.
I've used command to cat the image Resolution. In this example I've 2 images. In a directory

```
find $PWD -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%i %wx%h\n' '{}' \;|awk '{print $NF}'
```

**OUTPUT** 
1280x720
640x362
I want them both to match if the file size is say it should say **Okay** else **Check the file resolution** and exit. 
I tried the command to convert the output in to two variables a1 and a2. But it is not working. I tried to copy paste the output to the terminal than it is working. Please help

```
 find $PWD -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%i %wx%h\n' '{}' \;|awk '{print $NF}'|egrep -n "x"|sed 's#:#=#g'|sed 's#^#a#g'|paste -sd ";"|bash
```

Comment: Do you have many files or just two? Why are you printing their names - surely you know their names?

Answer (score 0):

You did

```
... | awk '{print $NF}'
```

and got

```
1280x720
640x362
```

I would harness GNU `AWK` as follows to check if all sizes match

```
... | awk '{arr[$NF]+=1}END{print length(arr)==1?"Everything match":"At least one mismatch"}'
```

Which will print either `Everything match` or `At least one mismatch`. Explanation: I use array `arr` for every encountered resolution I increase value for that resolution by 1. At `END` if `arr` has exactly `1` distinct key I `print` `Everything match` otherwise `At least one mismatch` using ternany operator i.e. `condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment! Please help me with how do I match it. As I tried this script on a similar dimension video it just says At list one match. The condition is I want to know if both of the videos are the same resolution or not if yes it should continue else exit the script.

Comment: @TechnologyEFXTV my code check if all feeded resolutions are same (and print `Everything match`) or at least one is different (then print `At least one match`) in particular for two elements it got it will check if both are same. What does *continue* mean in regards to AWK?

Comment: Thank you. You cleared my doubt. Continue means script should go on to the next command or should stop on no match. Like exit on no match. echo match on match. Thanks, I got the solution.